# My navigation is messed up, and the right border isn't working

Tags: html, css, navigation, border

I tried to get the right border to go in between each section and have each word be a separate span, but it just doesn't want to work. I would love some help. All 4 borders go to the side and are not even big enough to take up the whole nav. Please tell me what is happening. I would post in image, but my rep isn't high enough. It is basically a nav with 4 different links and I want little borders between them, but when I put spans on all of the list items then the borders get small and clump up to the right of the nav. Like the spans aren't even on the list items.

Here is my HTML for the nav:

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <span class="navSpace"><li>Home</li></span>
        <span class="navSpace"><li>Services</li></span>
        <span class="navSpace"><li>Info</li></span>
        <span class="navSpace"><li>FAQ's</li></span>
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

And the CSS for my nav:

```
#navigation{
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
#navigation li{
list-style: none;
text-align: left;
display: inline;
float: left;
padding: 5px;
margin-right: 25px;
font-size: 20px;
}
.navSpace{
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px white;
border-right: 2px solid black;

}
```

Sorry for no picture and thankyou in advance.

Comment: Your html is wrong. the children of an ui tag must be li tags
http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/ul.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268834/nesting-html-tags-inside-ul-other-than-li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving this line:

```
border-right: 2px solid black;
```

into your `#navigation li` section.

EDIT: As a couple of the other answers stated, you should simplify this and remove the `<span>` elements, for the sake of clarity and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

remove span from li in your html and use this css

```
 #navigation li{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px white;   
    }
```

and if you want smaller border then this make image of your border and use it as a background image in your css

```
 #navigation li{
        list-style: none;
        text-align: left;
        float: left;
        padding: 0px 5px;
        margin-right: 25px;
        font-size: 20px;
        background-image:url (your image path here);

        }
```