# nesting other html tags inside ul except li

Tags: html

Are these code pieces syntactically correct? I am using first code piece to build a navigation (nesting header tag inside ul). If it is wrong or it is a bad practice what are the drawbacks.

```
<ul class="site-title left">
  <header>
   <li><h1>site title</h1></li>
  </header>                         
</ul>
```

and

```
<ul class="site-title left">
  <span>
   <li><h1>site-title</h1></li>
  </span>                           
</ul>
```

Comment: drawback is that it might not work or look different in different browsers

Comment: i would suggest: `<li class="header">`

Comment: Also: for checking validity of the syntax, the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) is your friend.

Comment: As the answers state, no this is not correct syntax. I'd also argue that that it's probably semantically incorrect as well. If it's navigation, the site title doesn't belong in it. FYI, the likely best solution for what you want is to simply use nested lists.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**No**

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/), [the ul element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/ul.html) is:

> The ul element represents a list of items, where the order of the items is not important — that is, where changing the order would not materially change the meaning of the document.
>
> The **items of the list are the li element child nodes of the ul element.**

So the children of the UL element **must** be `li` elements.

More specifically, it says under the `ul` tag:

> Content model:
>
> ```
>    Zero or more li elements.
> ```

It is however, perfectly legal to do:

```
<ul class="site-title left">
   <li><span><h1>site-title</h1></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Amazing what you can find in the specs, eh? I find this version a bit easier to work with for this sort of thing: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/ul.html

Comment: There has been an ongoing effort these last couple of years to make spec more readable. The end goal is for developers and implementors (like browser vendors) to be easily able to access this sort of information :) Thanks for the dev.w3.org link, they _are_ more readable, I'm just used to reading the nightlies :) I'll update the link.

Comment: They're doing a great job with the specs, the latest ones are very clear, concise, and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Validation Output: 1 Error

Error Line 25, Column 51: Element h1 not allowed as child of element span in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

```
            <li><span><h1 class="Tabellenkopf">Menü</h1></span></li>
```

Comment: This is not what he is asking for!!! I think he want to know if an element that is not a li can be placed as first child of an ul block. And the answare seems to be no