# How to create a megamenu in this situation?

Tags: html, css

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu">
    <li class="has-mega-menu">
        <a href="#">Getting Pregnant</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <h3>Topics</h3>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Pregnancy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">After Pregnancy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New Born</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New Parents</a></li>
</ul>
```

The thing is that the `h3` or `p` isnt allowed as a child of a `ul`. In my situattion I need to add a title like "Topics" then below some `li`s . HWhat is the best option to do this? The correct one?
Thanks

Comment: Use a span tag instead of h3. Then in CSS style the span tag to look like an h3.

Comment: Surround by `<li>`? @dowomenfart is `<span>` allowed in `<ul>`?

Comment: @IkoTikashi put span inside of li http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268834/nesting-html-tags-inside-ul-other-than-li

Comment: @dowomenfart I know, but using `<span>` instead of `<h3>` (as you stated) is not correct , since there's no `<li>` around it.

Comment: HOTDOG! Missed that thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to semantically add heading to a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935262/how-to-semantically-add-heading-to-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :
Remove the

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
     <h3>Topics</h3>
</ul>
```

and add a `div` instead. So this way w3c will validate it.
So we will have:

```
                    <ul id="menu-main-menu">
                        <li class="has-mega-menu">
                            <a href="#">Getting Pregnant</a>
                            <div >
                                <h2></h2>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pregnancy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">After Pregnancy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">New Born</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">New Parents</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct, semantical way to do this would be to add a `<section>` for the submenu:

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu">
    <li class="has-mega-menu">
        <a href="#">Getting Pregnant</a>
        <section class="sub-menu>
            <h3>Topics</h3>
            <ul>
                <!-- Items -->
            </ul>
        </section>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Pregnancy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">After Pregnancy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New Born</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New Parents</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also, if you're going to have a "Topics" label on every section of the mega menu, you should probably put it in a `span` and the actual title of the category in your `h3`.

Source: [How to semantically add heading to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935262/how-to-semantically-add-heading-to-a-list)