# Can't find the correct jQuery selector for this element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have repeating blocks of html that look like this :

```
<div class="pod-control">

  <a class="fap-single-track"></a>

    <a class="pod-dl"></a>

    <div class="add-music"><a class="add_mycrate"></a></div>

    <div class="added-music"></div>

</div>
```

I'm using jQuery to get the info from the "a.add_mycrate" class and then do some ajax stuff with the contents, this is all working just fine.

But on the response I am trying to .show a previously .hidden div "added-music" and I just can't seem to find the correct selector for it.

This is what I'm using :

```
var $this = jQuery(this);                  

    jQuery.post(myCrate.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        $this.closest('.add-music').remove();

        $this.closest('.pod-control').find('.added-music').show();

        alert(response);
    });
```

The line that is giving me trouble is :

```
$this.closest('.pod-control').find('.added-music').show();
```

After reading a bunch of posts I know that I need to move the selector up to the top level (from a.add_mycrate to .pod-control) so I can then .find .added-music but I also know I'm doing it wrong as whatever I try won't show this div.

Comment: `li` should be inside `ul`.

Comment: `li` is not a valid child of `div`. Your browser is probably moving your `li` outside of `pod-control` so your selector will not work as you expect

Comment: This is not valid HTML so you cannot have this working.

Comment: The UL tags are outside of the code I provided here. Do you really think that deserved a down vote on my question?

Comment: @Turnip <ul> & <li> element 's have been removed from the page (they were remnants left over from something previous and no longer required. But this still doesn't work.

Comment: I'd also like the big man that down voted this question to explain his reasons for doing so please.

Comment: Which tag `jQuery(this);` represent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the .add-music *after* you have shown the .added-music.
Which means: swap the two lines above the alert.

My suspicion is, that since the whole event is bound to the link which gets removed, it also stops executing the code bound to it.

EDIT: Or don't remove() it at all, but rather .hide() it.

Comment: Yep that worked a treat. Would have never thought to show before removing as the div's occupy the same screen space. That's brilliant, thank you @niorad ;)

Answer (score 0):

A problem is caused by the badly nested tags in the `ul` element.  See this [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17268862/4746328) for details.

A possible solution would be to do something like this:

```
<li class="pod-control">
  <a class="fap-single-track"></a>

  <a class="pod-dl"></a>

  <div class="add-music">
    <a class="add_mycrate"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="added-music"></div>
</li>
```

This way elements inside `li` all share a common and identifiable parent node (`.pod-control`) making them much easier to traverse and target with JQuery `.parent()`, `.children()`, `.siblings()`, `.next()`, `.prev()` methods and `:first-child`, `:last-child`, `:nth-child` selectors etc.